How to change key binding in grep mode?
The Enter key (RET) is originally bound to the "compile-goto-error" function in grep mode.
But I want to bind it to my function.
The problem is that the keymap has changed, but the function is not called.

Here's my code in init.el:
(defun custom/compile-goto-error (&optional event)
  "Go to the error and close the grep window."
  (interactive (list last-input-event))
  (message " ---------- #2455 @ init.el")
  (compile-goto-error event)
  (delete-other-windows))  

(defun custom/set-grep-mode-keymap ()
  ;; (define-key grep-mode-map "\C-m" 'custom/compile-goto-error)
  (define-key grep-mode-map "\r" 'custom/compile-goto-error)
  (define-key compilation-mode-map "\r" 'custom/compile-goto-error)
  (define-key compilation-minor-mode-map "\r" 'custom/compile-goto-error)
  (define-key grep-mode-map "w" 'custom/compile-goto-error))

(add-hook 'grep-mode-hook 'custom/set-grep-mode-keymap)
    
;; I've tried other hooks, but all of them failed.
;; (add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'custom/set-grep-mode-keymap)
;; (add-hook 'compilation-start-hook 'custom/set-grep-mode-keymap)
;; (add-hook 'compilation-minor-mode-hook 'custom/set-grep-mode-keymap)


I'm trying the same for the occur mode, but it works.
Code in init.el:
(defun custom/occur-mode-goto-occurrence (&optional event)
  (interactive (list last-nonmenu-event))
  (occur-mode-goto-occurrence-other-window)
  (delete-other-windows))
  
(define-key occur-mode-map "\C-m" 'custom/occur-mode-goto-occurrence)

Is there something wrong?
I am using Emacs 29 on Windows 10.

What does C-h k RET tell you?

Make sure to do C-h k RET at two places: on the links at the beginning of the line and on the text at the end of the line. Different keymaps  may be used in the two places.

Thanks for your advice.@NickD

@phils Thanks for your advice.

I found the second map that needs to be set (in addition to grep-mode-map) for compile-goto-error. Now it works.
  (define-key compilation-button-map "\r" 'custom/compile-goto-error)

